# Android Xml driven flash(swf) gallery

Tags: android, xml, actionscript-3, flash

I've designed a gallery in swf and i wanted it to run on android. If it was a normal gallery it would work. But the gallery is XML based. Hence im finding it a little difficult

I load the swf onto a UILoader.The swf inturn calls the xml
When i run  the apk in android emulator i get a blank image, where as if i run it on air for android in flash, it works perfectly.
I think the problem is with the xml file loading onto the swf

I've used Flash CS 5.5

`import fl.display.ProLoader;
    var fl_ProLoader_2:ProLoader;//This variable keeps track of whether you want to load or   unload the SWF
    var fl_ToLoad_2:Boolean = true;`

```
if (fl_ToLoad_2)
{
fl_ProLoader_2 = new ProLoader();
fl_ProLoader_2.load(new URLRequest("scroll tut.swf"));
addChild(fl_ProLoader_2);
}
else
{
fl_ProLoader_2.unload();
removeChild(fl_ProLoader_2);
fl_ProLoader_2 = null;
}// Toggle whether you want to load or unload the SWF
fl_ToLoad_2 = ! fl_ToLoad_2;
```

Please provide a good solution

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add every event listener for the `UILoader` class, and print out the event message. I think there is a sandbox security error.

Comment: Whats sandbox security? Is it something to do with flash? Do I have to make changes in Air For Android settings?

Comment: @MonishChandra For the security reason Adobe put the flash file into several sandbox. This will prevent your flash to access some resource. You can get more information from the official document here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e3f.html